# Irregular "smooth" shading / artifacts still present with flat face smoothing selected

Tags: shaders, normals, topology

When using eevee and enabling "Scene World", with Mesh > Shading > Flat faces enabled, blurred and irregular shadows still appear.
I have checked/recalculated the normals (they are all correctly oriented; Display > Face orientation shows all blue faces), cleared edges, and tried everything in Mesh > Clean up to no avail. I wonder if it is the topology, since I have a few triangles and even fewer n-gons? I have tried my best manually to make sure there are no extra faces/vertices either.

I would like to have all of the shading follow the rest of the body.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image: OBJECT smooth shading enabled: artifact still present]

Comment: _Shading_ > _Flat_ only means that the the edge angles between faces are not smoothed out, i.e. you can see where one face ends and the other begins because of the harsh change in shading (if their normals are differing from each other). It has nothing to do with the shadow an object casts onto a surface. The sharpness of shadows depends on the _Radius_ or _Size_ you've set in the light properties, and when using _Eevee_ instead of _Cycles_ additionally also in the _Shadow_ and/or _Contact Shadows_ setting of the light and the _Shadows_ settings in the scene's _Render Properties_.